# How to add a link to already opened pull request on github?

Tags: github, gitlab-ci

I am a noob to github's organziation settings and all. Don't know if we need these settings for the question Im about to ask.

So what I want to achieve is to show the already opened pull request's link on a subsequent push. In the past when working with bitbucket and gitlab with a development team, the link used to appear both on the initial push to create a pull request and also on subsequent commits push to PR. But in my current workflow it only appears on initial push to create the PR. (*Note* I haven't been setting up repositories in the past myself and just starting to explore this area so no idea if in the past lead engineer has been adding any settings or not)

This is what I see on initial push:

[image]

And this is on subsequent push. No link to already opened pull request

[image]

What am I missing? And is it even possible to do?

Any read or keywords to search for would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a remark : when running `git push`, lines prefixed with `remote:`  are actually generated by *something on the remote* ("something" = a script or a program or ...). If you want to see something more, check if there is some setting on Github's side to re-display the merge request number when you update a branch (I must confess I don't know if and how this can be done).

---

If you want to find what pull request is linked to a known branch, there is a specific search filter (in the web GUI) for that : [`head:branch_name`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-branch-name)

As an example :

Here is how you could get PR #1037 (linked to a branch named `leaksan-100-part2`) on git's repository :

[`is:pr head:leaksan-100-part2`](https://github.com/git/git/pulls?q=is%3Apr+head%3Aleaksan-100-part2)

If you want to get this from a script, you should probably use Github's API :

the doc to [Pulls API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-pull-requests) mentions a `base` attribute :

```
base    string  query   Filter pulls by base branch name. Example: gh-pages.
```